# Working with struct data type using pysprak

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

I am planning to handle struct data type in pyspark, which accounts map data type in dynamodb. Since i am planning to perform transformations in dynamodb table which has a map attribute i want to achieve the same using pyspark. 
I want to handle health attribute in this case.

```
{
  "file_name": "employeesalarydata",
  "folder_name": "doc_consumption_employeesalarydata",
  "Health": {
    "New version - Veracity unavailable": "A new dataset is available but IDQ rules are not generated yet"
  },
  "last_modified_date": "2020-05-13T10:10:37.519Z",
  "resource_id": "6df1e646-a16d-11ea-a60e-d43b04339964"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Nice but not able to understand where do you want help or you are looking for suggestions?

Comment: i want to perform spark.sql operations on the fields in heath attribute, i need sample code for reference.

Comment: Good! Can you update your question with some sample operation you want to perform?For example, give two sample records and ask for you want to do and If you get an error, post it here in SO

Answer (score 0):

I think https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object should help you to get object.

Example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

spark.table('schema.table')\
.select(f.get_json_object('column_name', '$.Health').alias('health'))\
.show()
```